# Excel Error in VBA " Run-time error '424': Object required at SET statement

Tags: excel, vba

I'm getting Run-time error '424' at the last line of the code and cannot undertand why. Any help please.

```
Dim sourceSh As Worksheet
Dim destSh As Worksheet
Dim FileName As String
Dim destWk As Workbook
Dim sourceWk As Workbook

FileName = "Data.xlsx"

Set destWk = Workbooks.Open(FileName)
Set sourceWk = DataEntry
Set sourceSh = sourceWk.Sheets(Data_Entry.Name)  'why here I'm not getting error !!
Set destSh = destWk.Sheets(Employees.Name)      'here I'm getting Run-time error 424.
```

I have cotroled speel check and everything looks fine.

Comment: is employees an object and did you set it correctly?

Comment: What is `DataEntry` and what is `Data_Entry` and what is `Employees` and do you use `Option Explicit`? And `FileName = "Data.xlsx"` needs a path. You cannot open a file `Workbooks.Open(FileName)` without specifying its path.

Comment: Data_Entry is a Code name of the sheet, where DataEntry is code name of the workbook (insted of ThisWorkbook), yes I have Option Explicit. FileName has a path... the file is oppening. the problem is on the last SET destSh.........

Comment: @Turan Aydin:  If "Data_Entry is a Code name of the sheet" then why do you assign a worksheet object "DataEntry" to "sourceWk", which is a workbook object?! Are you sure?

Comment: DataEntry is a Workbook, so source book is "Set sourceWk = DataEntry", when I debug.Print sourceWk , the result is correct. when I debug.Print sourceSh result also is correct

Comment: @Turan Aydin: OK, now that we know that "DataEntry is a Workbook" and not a worksheet, let's examine the "Employees" object: What is it?

Comment: when I compile the sub , I'm getting error "Varable not defined" for "Employees" in "Set destSh = destWk.Sheets(Employees.Name)"

Comment: @Turan Aydin: Absolutely! So, what SHOULD IT BE, this "Employees"?

Comment: If Employees is a worksheet code name that is in another workbook you would need to add the workbook reference in otherwise it's looking at the activeworkbook.

Comment: Dim FileName As String: FileName = "path/Data.xlsx"
    MsgBox FileName  'is correct
    Dim sourceWb As Workbook: Set sourceWb = DataEntry 'def source workbook
    MsgBox sourceWb.Name 'is correct
    Dim sourceSh As Worksheet: Set sourceSh = sourceWb.Sheets(Data_Entry.Name) 'def source sheet
    MsgBox sourceSh.Name ' is correct
    Dim destWb As Workbook: Set destWb = Workbooks.Open(FileName) 'def and open destination workbook 
    MsgBox destWb.Name 'is correct 
    Dim destSh As Worksheet: Set destSh = destWb.Sheets(Employees.Name) 'dest sheet - now : error 9

Comment: The line `Set destSh = destWb.Sheets(Employees.Name)` cannot work. It could only work if `Employees` were in `ThisWorkbook`, the workbook containing this code. But it would be overcomplicated because you could just do `Set destSh = Employees`. Read the comments in my posted function.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting a worksheet object "destSh" by assigning to it some worksheet from the workbook "destWk".

If "Employees" is an existing worksheet's code name then there should be no error (BTW, just

```
Set destSh = destWk.Employees
```

would suffice in this case).

If "Employees" is a worksheet name (tab caption) then you should have written

```
Set destSh = destWk.Sheets("Employees")
```

Since you did not, it is likely not the case...

So, the only conclusion possible is that neither version of "Employees" exists in "destWk".

Comment: It is easy to test your first `Set` statement. Open two new workbooks. In the first (`Book1`) insert a module. Create a sub and place the following two lines in it: `Dim destSh As Worksheet` and `Set destSh = Workbooks("Book2").Sheet1`, or just use `Debug.Print Workbooks("Book2").Sheet1.Name` and see `Run-time error '438'` occurring.

Comment: @VBasic2008: You are absolutely correct: it is easy to test, the way you describe or any other. I hope Turan Aydin has done that by now.

Answer (score 0):

### Define Worksheet by Code Name

- I would suggest that you just use `Data_Entry` in `ThisWorkbook`; there is no need to assign it to a variable (`SourceSh`) when it is already defined.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub wsByCodename()

    Dim sourceSh As Worksheet
    Dim destSh As Worksheet
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim destWk As Workbook
    
    ' The following should contain the 'complete' path, e.g. "C:\Test\Data.xlsx".
    FileName = "Data.xlsx"
    Set destWk = Workbooks.Open(FileName)
    
    Set destSh = defineWorksheetByCodeName(destWk, "Employees")
    Set sourceSh = Data_Entry

End Sub

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      In a specified workbook, NOT containing this code, returns
'               the worksheet (object) which is specified by its code name.
' Remarks:      If it is expected that a worksheet might get renamed
'               or moved to another position, it is best to refer to it
'               by its code name. In 'ThisWorkbook', the workbook containing
'               this code, you will use just e.g. 'Sheet1'.
'               But in another workbook, you could use this function,
'               because you CANNOT use e.g. 'ActiveWorkbook.Sheet1'.
' Example:      Const WorksheetCodeName As String = "Sheet1"
'               Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
'               Dim ws As Worksheet
'               Set ws = defineWorksheetByCodeName(wb, WorksheetCodeName)
'               If ws Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' or whatever.
'               ' Continue with code...
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function defineWorksheetByCodeName(Book As Workbook, _
                                   ByVal WorksheetCodeName As String) _
         As Worksheet
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In Book.Worksheets
        If StrComp(ws.CodeName, WorksheetCodeName, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            Set defineWorksheetByCodeName = ws
            Exit For
        End If
    Next ws
End Function
```

Comment: yes you are right the codenames are not qualifiable...what a pity. Thank you very much for the help and for the Function... I just wondering is it possible to do it with Class Module...